# Arbitrary database connection on the fly in Django

Tags: database, django

I'm developing a platform where each user has his own database (PostgreSQL, using templates). So after logging in to the system I need Django models to use this user's database.

The question: is there a way of doing it or I'm just trying to make Django do the impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: write your own middleware and database router.
Check this link - http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2037/ - it should help you to get started.